# Space and Time Estimation Of Xmlparsing

Tags: c#, .net, xml, parsing, xml-serialization

I have to develope a function which will take string (xml string) as input and return parsed result (in object format).

I am new to C# .Net so from net I find out that there are number of ways to do this:

1. Xml Serialization
2. Xml TextReader
3. XmlDocument
4. XDocument (and so on)

I wanted to know which way is better (in terms of time and space) considering that every second this function has to parse on and average 10-20 string (of avg 1000-2000 characters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For amount of data you planning to process it pretty much does not matter what you use. Write code that works/looks good and than measure - if your estamate of ~40K per second is reasonable you unlikley find any measurable difference between all approaches.

XmlSerialzation is the easiest to use and requires the least amount of code if you can choose format of your XML. The XmlDocument and XDocument are higher level concepts on top XmlReader, so if you looking for highest speed raw XmlReader would give you the most options.

Comment: So from your point of view if I use XmlReader amount of work will be more compare to XmlSerialization, but it will be faster than XmlSerialization?

Comment: @vrajs5, With XMLReader you CAN get better memory usage and faster loading as other approaches are built on top of it, but it will require the most efforts. From theoretical point of view all XML reading methods have about the same speed - they all need to read whole XML, from memory consumption point of view XmlReader by itself does not consume much memory as it does not need to keep any knowledge about the document outside of current element unlikle other approaches that have to build XML tree or objects.

Comment: Tnx.. I think I have to create atleast 2 method one with XmlReader and XmlSerialzation.. and check the results...

Answer (score 2):

XmlTextReader goes over the file line by line, so it can handle very big files, and very useful when you don't need to parse the entire xml.

XmlDocument builds a DOM on loading the file, which is very easy to browse through, though very time\mem consuming on big xml's.

Answer (score 0):

Just use MSXML. Profile and measure the performance, *then* decide whether you need an alternate solution.

```
using MSXML;
DOMDocument30 doc = new DOMDocument30();
doc.async = false;
if (doc.load("somefile.xml"))
{
  // process document here
}
```

Once you have some concrete measurements, then you can start looking at information e.g. in [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647804.aspx) But you may not find it's necessary at all.

Comment: Thanks.. Thing is I cannot create multiple solution and measure it... I know what your are saying is one of the best method to measure performance.. But I want overall idea...

Comment: -1 for suggestion to use MSXML (as it usage of MSXML is not supported in processes with .Net runtime), +1 for mentionig profiling and link to article about processing XML in .Net world. As result balances out to 0.